# Can a GPIO pin be used instead of a I2C pin?

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio, i2c

Can a sensor with a I2C output be used with arbitrary GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi?

For example, what about the Sht31 temperature/humidity sensor: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2857

Comment: The Pi has the I2C bus on pins 3 and 5 as seen here https://pinout.xyz/

Answer (score 1):

The Pi3 has two hardware I2C buses only one of which should normally be used (one bus is reserved for HATs.)

Additionally there is device tree support for software I2C buses on arbitrary GPIO.

For both the above you need to make configuration changes in `/boot/config.txt` as documented in `/boot/overlays/README`.

Additionally there are many software I2C implementations which may be useful in special circumstances (e.g. my pigpio library with [bit bang I2C](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#bbI2COpen)).